# Is it possible to register an IIS Isapi mapping with a setup project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, deployment, installation

It would be useful for example to deploy an asp.net mvc app in iis 6 without the extra steps.
In this case i would like to register a map for "*.mvc" to the asp.net handler 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Wix and xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension" is defined in your Wix element, this should work:

```
<iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="mvc" CheckPath="yes" Script="yes"
               Executable="[NETFRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
               Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" />
```

Note the [NETFRAMEWORKROOT] property, I wouldn't rely on C:\WINDOWS.

FWIW, we place this inside the iis:WebApplication element of a iis:WebVirtualDir element.